# SQLite : discrepancy when importing CSV file into table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with last column of integer type and I am trying to import data from a csv file into this table.
Some records have no value for this last column. When importing, I see that the last record is getting handled differently than others. For all other such records, this column is populated with empty string ''. However, in case of last record, it is getting populated with null.

Why is this happening?
Perhaps, if I include a newline character after the last line, it could solve the problem, but thats not an option here. What else can I do to address this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every record having a missing third column value *other* than the last row in the file had empty string, you could just try the following update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col3 = ''
WHERE col3 IS NULL;
```

This would work, assuming that at most only the final row would match the above update.  The best thing to do here would probably be to fix your CSV file and put a CRLF onto the final line.

Comment: Thanks Tim...that would work...but thats a hack...it would be interesting to know why this is happening...trying to understand if this is some sort of a known issue/bug happening because of some sort of a configuration which could be tweaked

Comment: If you can describe how you are importing CSV into SQLite, perhaps more can be said.  Adding CRLF to the last line would also fix this, and you may think that's a hack too, but it works.

Comment: you are right...adding newline to the file is a hack too...and thats not an option for me ( mentioned in problem statement)...importing using the .import <file> <table> SQLite command